# facebook share api; Inferred Property

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, facebook

I've been trying to let users be able share posts in my web. so far users can share the right url and right description. for image and title, I'm not getting right ones.
I used facebook debugger, and it shows

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing    The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

in header I have,

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="myweb.net"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="{{post.title}}"/>    
<meta property="og:description" content="{{post.content|safe}}" />
<meta property="article:author" content="myweb" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{{request.build_absolute_uri}}" />
 {% if post.main_image %}

<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.get_image_url}}" />

  {% elif post.video %}
  {% video post.video as my_video %}
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ my_video.thumbnail }}" />
        {% endvideo %}
  {% elif post.url %}

<meta property="og:image" content=="{{post.image}}" />

{% else %}

<meta property="og:image" content=="{{post.thumbnail}}" />

{% endif %}
```

and in body

```
<ul class="rrssb-buttons clearfix">
  <li class="rrssb-email">
    <!-- Replace subject with your message using URL Endocding: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ -->
    <a href="mailto:?subject=Check%20out%20how%20ridiculously%20responsive%20these%20social%20buttons%20are&amp;body=http%3A%2F%2Fkurtnoble.com%2Flabs%2Frrssb%2Findex.html">
      <span class="rrssb-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28"><path d="M20.11 26.147c-2.335 1.05-4.36 1.4-7.124 1.4C6.524 27.548.84 22.916.84 15.284.84 7.343 6.602.45 15.4.45c6.854 0 11.8 4.7 11.8 11.252 0 5.684-3.193 9.265-7.398 9.3-1.83 0-3.153-.934-3.347-2.997h-.077c-1.208 1.986-2.96 2.997-5.023 2.997-2.532 0-4.36-1.868-4.36-5.062 0-4.75 3.503-9.07 9.11-9.07 1.713 0 3.7.4 4.6.972l-1.17 7.203c-.387 2.298-.115 3.3 1 3.4 1.674 0 3.774-2.102 3.774-6.58 0-5.06-3.27-8.994-9.304-8.994C9.05 2.87 3.83 7.545 3.83 14.97c0 6.5 4.2 10.2 10 10.202 1.987 0 4.09-.43 5.647-1.245l.634 2.22zM16.647 10.1c-.31-.078-.7-.155-1.207-.155-2.572 0-4.596 2.53-4.596 5.53 0 1.5.7 2.4 1.9 2.4 1.44 0 2.96-1.83 3.31-4.088l.592-3.72z"/></svg></span>
      <span class="rrssb-text">email</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="rrssb-facebook">
    <!--  Replace with your URL. For best results, make sure you page has the proper FB Open Graph tags in header: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/ -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{request.build_absolute_uri}}" class="popup">
      <span class="rrssb-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 29 29"><path d="M26.4 0H2.6C1.714 0 0 1.715 0 2.6v23.8c0 .884 1.715 2.6 2.6 2.6h12.393V17.988h-3.996v-3.98h3.997v-3.062c0-3.746 2.835-5.97 6.177-5.97 1.6 0 2.444.173 2.845.226v3.792H21.18c-1.817 0-2.156.9-2.156 2.168v2.847h5.045l-.66 3.978h-4.386V29H26.4c.884 0 2.6-1.716 2.6-2.6V2.6c0-.885-1.716-2.6-2.6-2.6z"/></svg></span>
      <span class="rrssb-text">facebook</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="rrssb-twitter">
    <!-- Replace href with your Meta and URL information  -->
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Ridiculously%20Responsive%20Social%20Sharing%20Buttons%20by%20%40dbox%20and%20%40joshuatuscan%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fkurtnoble.com%2Flabs%2Frrssb%20%7C%20http%3A%2F%2Fkurtnoble.com%2Flabs%2Frrssb%2Fmedia%2Frrssb-preview.png"
    class="popup">
      <span class="rrssb-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28"><path d="M24.253 8.756C24.69 17.08 18.297 24.182 9.97 24.62a15.093 15.093 0 0 1-8.86-2.32c2.702.18 5.375-.648 7.507-2.32a5.417 5.417 0 0 1-4.49-3.64c.802.13 1.62.077 2.4-.154a5.416 5.416 0 0 1-4.412-5.11 5.43 5.43 0 0 0 2.168.387A5.416 5.416 0 0 1 2.89 4.498a15.09 15.09 0 0 0 10.913 5.573 5.185 5.185 0 0 1 3.434-6.48 5.18 5.18 0 0 1 5.546 1.682 9.076 9.076 0 0 0 3.33-1.317 5.038 5.038 0 0 1-2.4 2.942 9.068 9.068 0 0 0 3.02-.85 5.05 5.05 0 0 1-2.48 2.71z"/></svg></span>
      <span class="rrssb-text">twitter</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

in javascript, I set it as rrssb document directed me to 
https://github.com/kni-labs/rrssb

```
<script type="text/javascript">

j

    Query(document).ready(function ($) {

      $('.rrssb-buttons').rrssb({
        // required:
        title: '{{post.title}}',
        url: window.location.href,

        // optional:
        description: '{{post.content|safe}}',
        emailBody: 'Usually email body is just the description + url, but you can customize it if you want'
      });
    });
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Facebook is not executing Javascript.

Comment: @WizKid that;s for rrssb

Comment: Give us a real URL, so that we can have a look at the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `=` sign from the last 2 `meta` tags. Facebook is unable to read the url because of the extra `=` sign.

```
<meta property="og:image" content=="{{post.image}}" />
                                 ^-------------------------- extra '='
{% else %}

<meta property="og:image" content=="{{post.thumbnail}}" />
                                 ^--------------------------- extra '='
```

Correct it to

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.image}}" />
{% else %}
<meta property="og:image" content="{{post.thumbnail}}" />
```

Comment: hello, the solution we tackled on the commenting has two problems. first one is when I try to make a comment then comment again, the second comment gets submitted twice. If I make one more comment third comment gets submitted multiple times as well. Second one is after I make a comment, and try to reply to a different comment, I am unable to unfold text box.....can you please check this issue? I desperately need some help for this.....

Comment: @mikebraa - I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Hello...can you help me with this today?I tried it twice and deleted cache but it happens same thing, did it work on yours? please let me know if you can help me with this today;)?